# How can I type Korean Yethangul on Ubuntu?

Tags: input-language, input, input-method, fcitx, korean

currently I have an Fcitx setup where I can easily switch between IBus Pinyin Chinese, Google Japanese Input, and Korean Hangul input.

However, I want to be able to type Yethangul, which are old Hangul characters, the same way you would be able to on Windows using Microsoft Yethangul IME.

Is there any way I can do this on Ubuntu? Preferably I'd want to use Fcitx and integrate it into there, but if I have to use other methods, I'm open to that too.

Thanks in advance!